# UINavigationController right button only text, no button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

How can I put a text that I want to be able to change at runtime in the right corner of my navigation bar? I would like it if I wouldn't have to create a UIBarButtonItem every time I change the text.

Comment: Where is your UINavigationBar defined?  Code or interface builder?

Comment: In storyboard, but I use self.navigationController to get it. I have created many UIBarButtonItems this way, but I don't seem to find a way to put a plain text instead of a button

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set arbitrary text then you need to create a new `UIBarButtonItem` each time with the new label. That's simple enough to do.

If you know ahead of time that the button will only have a few possible labels then you can do the following:

```
 UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"firstTitle" style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(someAction:)];
 btn.possibleTitles = @[ @"firstTitle", @"secondTitle", @"thirdTitle" ];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btn;
```

Then later when you want to change the title you can do:

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"secondTitle";
```